# Incluir com parâmetros

Tags: php, query

Como faço para que eu inclua um outro arquivo php passando informações com ele, por exemplo tenho o objetivo de incluir um php que tem um sistema de mensagem que cria um html temporário que da erro:

Por exemplo quero que ao dar `include('info.php?page=sem-nome');` ele retorne 
um **echo** com o erro amostrado:

```
<?php 
    echo "<h2 style=\"color: red\">Página não encontrada: " . $_GET['page'] . "</h2>";
?>
```

Isso seria possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível! Caso realmente queira realizar `include` passando parâmetro via `GET`, deverá passar a **URL completa do arquivo** `info.php`.

Exemplo:

```
include 'http://www.exemplo.com.br/info.php?page=sem nome';
```

Caso não queira utilizar a URL completa, pode fazer assim:

**arquivo1.php**

```
<?php
$page = 'sem nome';
include('info.php');
```

**info.php**

```
<?php
echo "<h2 style=\"color: red\">Página não encontrada: " . $page . "</h2>";
```